# Assign TRUE to entries in a character vector that satisfy pattern at first element only (R)

Tags: r, pattern-matching

Say we have the character vector

```
x <- as.character(c("101H","208H","335","467","521C","689J","704","800"))
```

Items above "500" (the last four entries) are to be marked as `TRUE`.  Simple enough if we could convert the vector to numeric and do `ifelse()`, but because of the embedded letters, NaNs will be introduced.

Instead I thought to use `library(stringr)` to tell R to recognize a pattern and assign `TRUE` to elements that satisfy the pattern.  However, something like

```
grepl("[5-9]",x)
```

doesn't work properly since R just looks for any occurrence of the pattern regardless where the pattern appears in the entry.

How can I tell R to only look at the first element of each entry?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grepl("[5-9]",x)` tells you which elements contain a 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9. `gsub` would be more appropriate.  To remove all letters before the check, provided there are only letters and numbers in the string, try

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x)) > 500
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

With regard to your last line, you can tell R to look only at the first character of each string with

```
substr(x, 1, 1)
```

Comment: A tremendously late response to let you know I accepted your answer. I did not realize I could "accept" an answer despite having too little reputation to "upvote".